# Converting Makefile to CMake using Flex and Bison

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake, bison, flex-lexer

I'm learning Bison/Flex and wanted to download already made C++ code.. I found this (http://www.jonathanbeard.io/tutorials/FlexBisonC++) article with already created parser. Now i wanted convert this (working) Makefile

```
CC    ?= clang
CXX   ?= clang++

EXE = my_wc

CDEBUG = -g -Wall

CXXDEBUG = -g -Wall

CSTD = -std=c99
CXXSTD = -std=c++14

CFLAGS = -Wno-deprecated-register -O0  $(CDEBUG) $(CSTD) 
CXXFLAGS = -Wno-deprecated-register -O0  $(CXXDEBUG) $(CXXSTD)


CPPOBJ = main mc_driver
SOBJ =  parser lexer

FILES = $(addsuffix .cpp, $(CPPOBJ))

OBJS  = $(addsuffix .o, $(CPPOBJ))

CLEANLIST =  $(addsuffix .o, $(OBJ)) $(OBJS) \
                 mc_parser.tab.cc mc_parser.tab.hh \
                 location.hh position.hh \
                stack.hh mc_parser.output parser.o \
                 lexer.o mc_lexer.yy.cc $(EXE)\

.PHONY: all
all: wc

wc: $(FILES)
    $(MAKE) $(SOBJ)
    $(MAKE) $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $(EXE) $(OBJS) parser.o lexer.o $(LIBS)


parser: mc_parser.yy
    bison -d -v mc_parser.yy
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o parser.o mc_parser.tab.cc

lexer: mc_lexer.l
    flex --outfile=mc_lexer.yy.cc  $<
    $(CXX)  $(CXXFLAGS) -c mc_lexer.yy.cc -o lexer.o

.PHONY: test
test:
    cd test && ./test0.pl

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -rf $(CLEANLIST)
```

to the CMake file

```
PROJECT(CTM)

CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8)

SET(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

FIND_PACKAGE(BISON)
FIND_PACKAGE(FLEX)

BISON_TARGET(
    CTMParser
    mc_parser.yy ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/mc_parser.tab.cpp
)

FLEX_TARGET(
    CTMLexer
    mc_lexer.l ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/mc_lexer.cpp
)

ADD_FLEX_BISON_DEPENDENCY(CTMLexer CTMParser)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})




ADD_EXECUTABLE(ctm      
    main.cpp
    mc_driver.cpp

    ${BISON_CTMParser_OUTPUTS}
    ${FLEX_CTMLexer_OUTPUTS}
)
```

Makefile works fine, but CMake ends with undefined reference error.

```
CMakeFiles/ctm.dir/mc_driver.cpp.o: In function `MC::MC_Driver::parse_helper(std::istream&)':
mc_driver.cpp:(.text+0x323): undefined reference to `MC::MC_Parser::MC_Parser(MC::MC_Scanner&, MC::MC_Driver&)'
```

Can somebody help me? Thanks for any answer.

EDIT:
After change typo, getting this

```
stack.hh:47:9: error: redefinition of default argument for ‘class S’
   class stack
```

Comment: It seems you've got a typo in `${BISON_CTMParser_OUTPUT}`. It is plural.

Comment: You are right, but now I'm getting much bigger (redefinition) error

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea to convert Makefiles to CMake files. They are very different. CMake is not a build system, but a meta build system or build system file generator.

Comment: It really helps me in future expansion of the project... But yeah, it's not really  nessesary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved by changing C++ version :) I missed that in Makefile is defined C++14 and I have in CMake C++11..

```
PROJECT(CTM)

CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8)

>>SET(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
<<SET(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

FIND_PACKAGE(BISON)
FIND_PACKAGE(FLEX)

BISON_TARGET(
    CTMParser
    mc_parser.yy ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/mc_parser.tab.cpp
)

FLEX_TARGET(
    CTMLexer
    mc_lexer.l ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/mc_lexer.cpp
)

ADD_FLEX_BISON_DEPENDENCY(CTMLexer CTMParser)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})




ADD_EXECUTABLE(ctm      
    main.cpp
    mc_driver.cpp

    ${BISON_CTMParser_OUTPUTS}
    ${FLEX_CTMLexer_OUTPUTS}
)
```